# Check if an object has a property

Tags: angularjs, object

How can I check if an object has a certain property in AngularJS?

Comment: If you don't know the name of property then you can simply check Object.keys(objName).length. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 40):

> You could use '**hasOwnProperty**' to check if object have the specific
>   property.

```
if($scope.test.hasOwnProperty('bye')){
  // do this   
}else{
  // do this then
}
```

Here's a  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J83Ch/) in jsFiddle.

Hope this helpful.

Comment: i pass object through directive (with '=') and in my directives controller I have this code snippet for initialization but I get TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined. do you know why?

Comment: @user2985439: It sounds like your object does not have a property `test`.

Comment: @user2985439 As Felix Kling mentioned, the object your directive referenced doesn't have 'test' property. Could you update your question for more details?

Comment: scope: {test:'='},controller($scope) {if($scope.test.hasOwnProperty('bye')) {// do stuff}} this returns the type error. I know test is defined because I pass it right through in the view...

Comment: Does the blash directive in the controller scope ? My blash directive just work as expected. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J83Ch/3/)

Comment: Suppose if i have an object whose keys are leveled let's assume obj.key1.key2.key3 then how can i check key3 exist in obj in one call.

Answer (score 2):

```
if('bye' in $scope.test) {}
else {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you probably will have value not just when linking your directive - it could be loaded by $http for example.

My advice would be:

```
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.$watch('test.hello', function(nv){ 
     if (!nv) return; 
     // nv has the value of test.hello. You can do whatever you want and this code
     // would be called each time value of 'hello' change
  });
}
```

or if you know that the value is assigned only one:

```
controller: function($scope) {
  var removeWatcher = $scope.$watch('test.hello', function(nv){ 
     if (!nv) return; 
     // nv has the value of test.hello. You can do whatever you want
     removeWatcher();
  });
}
```

This code will remove watcher the value of 'test.hello' was assigned (from any controller, ajax, etc etc)